# How to do large file integrity check

Tags: algorithm, checksum, data-integrity, integrity

I need to do an integrity check for a single big file. I have read the SHA code for Android, but it will need one another file for the result digest. Is there another method using a single file?

I need a simple and quick method. Can I merge the two files into a single file?

The file is binary and the file name is fixed. I can get the file size using fstat. My problem is that I can only have one single file. Maybe I should use CRC, but it would be very slow because it is a large file.

My object is to ensure the file on the SD card is not corrupt. I write it on a PC and read it on an embedded platform. The file is around 200 MB.

Comment: If you can't safely append the checksum to the file or write it into some "unused" location in it, the next thing you should consider is placing the checksum into the file's name.

Comment: Have you actually benchmarked CRC of the file. What makes you think it will be very slow? I'd guess on the low end 8MB/s over 200 MB or 25 seconds could be accomplished in a background thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store the hash somehow, no way around it.

You can try writing it to the file itself (at the beginning or end) and skip it when performing the integrity check. This can work for things like XML files, but not for images or binaries.
You can also put the hash in the filename, or just keep a database of all your hashes.

It really all depends on what your program does and how it's set up.

Comment: Thank you very much.Can you tell me why it can not work for binary file?

Comment: That works fine for non-text files, better even because a text file shouldn't really contain binary data (I suppose you could write it in hex though) - of course other programs trying to use that file may take issue with it

Comment: @ray: binary files are typically expected to have a fixed structure and sizes of their parts. If you prepend or append or insert something to/in a binary file, the consuming code will likely interpret the file's data incorrectly as it wouldn't be able to tell from, say, a byte value whether it's the data it expects or can skip. XML-like files are expected to have variable structure and are usually parsed/read in a different way, the reading code would normally look at the contents of entities named or located in a special way/place.

Comment: @ray, most files have an expected structure. Certain fields are supposed to be at x bytes from the start. If you insert extra stuff you've shifted everything and the file is practically corrupted. Some files can tolerate data at the end, some can't, for the same reason.

Comment: @ray, the general term for what you want is storing metadata. That's data about your data. Some filesystems support this natively, but it's rarely used because of compatibility reasons. This is why MP3s have ID3 tags, why JPEGs have EXIF, etc. It's to store data about the data. If you're looking to only work with one or two types of files and they have a mechanism like this then you can take advantage. I think some types of executables have a metadata mechanism, but I guarantee you that using it will be more work than storing the hash separately.